# select last n lines of a text field in postgres on the bases of a split character

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a text field in PostgreSQL in which I have stored content of a text file.

Query:

```
SELECT m_Field 
FROM m_table 
WHERE id = 1;
```

When I run query the response is:

> 'The basic steps are shown here and rely heavily on using snort as an IPS.\n1. Utilize snort IPS to prevent downloads of initial infection vectors\n2. Utilize snort IPS to prevent downloads of Trojan executable\n3. Utilize snort IPS to alert on current infections\n4. Kill and remove malware from the initally infected machine\n5. Kill other instances of malware and remove from machines.\n6. Prevent further infection and ensure business success.'

Now I want to read only last n lines from this field on the basis of a split character which in this case is `\n`

Is it possible to do this using some SQL query, or do I have to read data from the column and then split it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using just SQL or any other framework?

Comment: i am using django.
But i preferably want it to be done mostly at the database end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in Python, you can get get query result and and split it on `\n` and and get last n lines like this

```
q = exec_query('SELECT m_Field FROM m_table WHERE id = 1;') # suppose you are executing with some function exec_query
last_n_lines = q.split('\n')[-n]
```

If you want to do this on database end, you can this like this

```
q = exec_query(SELECT string_to_array(m_Field, '\n') FROM m_table WHERE id = 1;)
last_n_lines = q[-n]
```

Here `string_to_array` is  a postgres function.

Answer (score 1):

An approach by PostgreSQL alone:

```
select id, rn, sentence
from (
    select
        id
      , reverse(sentence) sentence
      , row_number() over(partition by id) rn
    from m_table, unnest(string_to_array(reverse(m_field), 'n\'))  sentence(token)
    ) t
where rn <= 3       --<< alter this number to suit
order by rn DESC
```

nb: Reversing the string is to enable selecting the last n lines

```
+----+----+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | rn |                           sentence                            |
+----+----+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |  3 | 4. Kill and remove malware from the initally infected machine |
|  1 |  2 | 5. Kill other instances of malware and remove from machines.  |
|  1 |  1 | 6. Prevent further infection and ensure business success.     |
+----+----+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

see: http://rextester.com/GXMED5871

Comment: i'm trying to do something similar and found that the order of the split array is not guaranteed by this approach

Comment: @pstanton are you able to provide a fiddle that demonstrates this loss of order?  e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: no, but i found it only to become an issue when querying multiple (more than 10) rows

Comment: @pstatnton I'm unable to replicate your claimed issue: [try this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f15b86d40540056bb353201911a6051)

Comment: it may be database versions or otherwise, i don't have time to replicate sorry

Comment: @pstanton It's s easy to use other versions, the fiddle already provided allows flipping across Postgres 9.5, 9.6, 10, 11, 12 and 13. and in all those versions it works as shown above. Perhaps " *i'm trying to do something similar* " actually isn't that similar at all.